# Why this exception Java?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, netbeans

I'm studying servlets and I'm trying to create a small program to get the hour through a class that I've created. But I've bee getting a exception. Here is the code:

User

```
package Business;

public class User {

    private String userId;

    public User() {
        userId = "";
    }

    public User(String id) {
        userId = id;
    }

    public void setUserId(String id) {
        userId = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

}
```

Hours

```
package Business;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import business.User;

public class Hours {

    private User user;
    private Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    private int min = 0;

    public Hours(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    public String getMinutes() {
        return Integer.toString(min);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

CheckUser

```
package process;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Business.User;
import Business.Hours;

public class CheckUser extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userId = request.getParameter("userID");
        User user1 = new User(userId);
        Hours h1 = new Hours(user1);
        String url = "/show.jsp";

        request.setAttribute("hours", h1);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userId = request.getParameter("userID");
        User user1 = new User(userId);
        Hours h1 = new Hours(user1);
        String url = "/show.jsp";

        request.setAttribute("hours", h1);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userId = request.getParameter("userID");
        User user1 = new User(userId);
        Hours h1 = new Hours(user1);
        String url = "/show.jsp";

        request.setAttribute("hours", h1);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Index

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Employees</h1>
        <form action="<%=response.encodeURL("CheckUser")%>" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Diogo">
            <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="1">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Show

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@ page import="Business.*, process.*" %>

        <%
            Hours h1 = (Hours) request.getAttribute("hours");
            String userId =h1.getUser().getUserId();
        %>
        <h1><%= userId %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Exception

> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type:     process.CheckUser.doGet(CheckUser.java:37)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) note The
> >     full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
> >     Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.

Comment: This is far too much code for a Stack Overflow question.  Please reduce your code to the absolute minimum required to exhibit the problem (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: use Eclipse or another IDE to detect compilation problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your package is `package Business;` but `Hours` class you have used `import business.User;`
remember package is case sensitive and as per standard it should be in lowercase

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an exception because you've deployed and attempted to execute code with a compilation error in it.

And I suspect that the compilation error is due to this line:

```
import business.User;
```

because you've actually declared the `User` class in the `Business` package, not the `business` package.

---

I have a feeling that you have shot yourself in the foot by ignoring the Java naming conventions:

- Package names should be all lower-case.
- The package name should be prefixed with a string that uniquely identifies your "business" to minimize the risk that your package/class names will collide with someone elses.  Conventionally this is a reverse DNS name

Comment: Thanks everybody. It was a silly mistake. One more doubt. When I compile and ask to return the userId on the show.jsp it appears Null. Does anybody knows why?

Comment: Probably because `"userId"` is not equal to `"userID"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different cases for in your package names:

```
package Business;
import business.User;
```

Package names should be all lower case (or at least each segment should start with a lower case) to follow normal Java naming conventions.

Normalize your `business` package and re-compile.

Answer (score 1):

The only think I can see that might be wrong is that in `Hours.java` you import a class `business.User` but in `CheckUser.java` you use a class `Business.User`.

Java is case sensitive. These are two different classes, so the types in the code does not match.

Answer (score 1):

In process.CheckUser you create a *Business.User*, but in your Business.Hour you require a *business.User*. Notice the different case in Business and business.